# kubernetes how to open nodeport for a single host

Tags: kubernetes

**Scenario:**

I have a k8s cluster with `host01`, `host02` and `host03`.

I'm running master on `host01` and slaves on `host02` and `host03`, and I want to open a port for client connections on master, ie I want to open: `host01:32702`.

Using following service.yaml, I managed to open `host01:32702`. To my surprise `host02:32702` and `host03:32702` are also open.

```
kind: Service
# ...
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: dashboard
    port: 8265
    targetPort: 8265
    nodePort: 32702
  selector:
    podonhost01: yes
```

**Questions:**

- Is this intended NodePort behavior? Is the selector not working?
- If yes, then why is this the intended NodePort behavior? If I have 1000s hosts, then single service will open port 32702 on all these hosts?
- How do I only open port 32702 on `host01` and not the rest of hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **externalIP**,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
  externalIPs:
    - HOST-01 IP
```

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips

Comment: Oh, you've removed `type: NodePort`. Works as intended. I thought I've read enough of k8s docs, but apparently not.